# Can I say "Draw a triangle around the strawberry"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Can I say "Draw a triangle around the strawberry" when I want someone who is reading a book, in which there is a picture of a strawberry, to draw a triangle in that book in such a way that the strawberry is inside of the triangle (in which case the triangle must, of course, be bigger than strawberry)?

Comment: It's not ambiguous or incorrect but it is super weird!

Comment: 100% of native literate English speakers will interpret this the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct but if you feel that using "around" would confuse by seemingly requiring a circle when you have asked for a triangle, you could say "surrounding" or "enclosing".

Comment: In other words "Find a strawberry on page 18 and draw one triangle surrounding/enclosing that strawberry" would be fine, right?

Comment: Yes.  Virtually no native speaker would quibble with that.

Comment: I don't think the original sentence is at all confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is correct, and should not be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

'Around' is usually used with drawing circles. Eg. Draw a circle around an object.

In popular culture, there's a "Kohler" commercial in which it's said, "Design a House around this..". Hope it explains the subtlety of the words.